# Unable to step into interface implementation configured by unity application block

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library

I have configured a set of interface implementations with EntLib. unity block. The constructor of implementation classes work fine as soon as I run the application:
1. The interface to implement
[image: Interface to implement]

when I run the application the cctor runs fine, which shows that unity resolution was successful:
[image: Unity Resolution success]

But when I try to call a method of this class, the code just passes through without actually invoking the function of the implemented class:
[image: Implementation does not get called]

> > Edit: Added on June 11, 2012
> >     Following is the Unity Configuration I have. (This is all the unity configuration I am doing)

```
 public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private static readonly IUnityContainer container;
    private static UnityControllerFactory factory = null;

    static UnityControllerFactory()
    {
        container = new UnityContainer();
        UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        section.Configure(container);
        factory = new UnityControllerFactory();
    }

    public static UnityControllerFactory GetControllerFactory()
    {
        return factory;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```

I am unable to step into this code and the implementation simply skips out without executing anything. What is wrong here?

Comment: If the code is totally skipped, this could be an indication that you need to refresh your dll's. Try to clean up your solution files and rebuild it. If this is not the case, use `F11` instead of `F10` when debugging

Comment: I have already tried cleaning the solution and using F11

Comment: When the debugger is stopped at the break point, right click on the line and select "step into specific", then choose the method you wish to step into.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: But how to make the code run normally? Any particular reason why this might be happening? Any traces I can view somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was with a yield statement, which does not step into the code until the result is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

When the debugger is stopped at the break point, right click on the line and select "step into specific", then choose the method you wish to step into.

Is this class/method in another assembly (not another project)? Its possible that the source for this class isn't loaded (or the debug symbols aren't refreshed correctly, restarting VS might fix it if that is the case.), so the debugger skips it.  Also the method might be decorated with the `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`, which causes the debugger to skip it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I tried to step into specific code, I could not find the interface implementation in the list of code blocks which I can step into, it only shows the interface method which I implemented. What could be wrong here?